# How to change value of datepicker using date stored in database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datepicker

I have a datepicker which I wanted to change the value based on the date retrieved from the database.

Here is what I have tried so far.

1.

```
rs.Open("select DATE_FORMAT(dateReceived,'%m-%d-%Y') as daterec from tblrequest
where refcode='TR-I-CGS-2016-1', cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)
dateReceived.Value = rs.Fields("daterec").Value
```

2.

```
 rs.Open("select dateReceived from tblrequest
where refcode='TR-I-CGS-2016-1', cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)
dateReceived.Value = rs.Fields("dateReceived").Value
```

both methods doesn't get me the result I wanted. What I need is the value of the dateReceived when the form loads is the date obtained from the database. Can anyone please help me. Thanks

Comment: What is the value store in your database and what is being displayed in the datetimepicker

Comment: "2016-12-10"...I've tried changing the custom format of the datepicker to the exact format of the data in the database, still not getting the value I wanted

Comment: have you tried formatting date in your query as #MM-dd-yyyy#

Comment: I've tried that as well...  rs.Open("select DATE_FORMAT(dateReceived,'%m-%d-%Y') as daterec from tblrequest where refcode='TR-I-CGS-2016-1', cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)

dateReceived.Value = rs.Fields("daterec").Value

Comment: What is the data type of your date in your database?

Comment: the data type is "date"

Comment: what actual value does your query return?